# VSCode TypeScript does not highlight Function return type disagreements

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

Pretty new to TypeScript and have been writing it exclusively in VSCode. VSCode highlights type "errors" for me which I have come to rely on heavily to catch my mistakes. I am not sure if this is part of TSLint or what or how it does it.

There is one type of "error" however, that I have found it does *not* catch. I want my class to have a property which is a handler function to be called at some time. A different object will pass in this handler to be called later.

I am typing out this property to have a certain call signature and return type. If I try to set this property to a function of a different call signature, VSCode highlights the mistake. However, if I try to set this property to a function with the wrong *return type* it does not catch it.

It may be best to demonstrate with a minimal example:

```
class Student {
    private enroller : () => Course
    constructor(){
        this.enroller = function() { return(this); }
    }
}

class Course {
    public courseNumber : number;
    constructor(){

    }
}
```

Now, the constructor of Student is setting the enroller property of Student to a function that returns the wrong type. The enroller should be a function that passes back a Course. However, I can set it to a function that passes back an itself (of Student class).

Is there anyway to configure TS/VSCode to highlight this type of mistake?

Honestly not sure what TSLint is and whether it is running in the background to highlight these syntax errors or if it is something I have to run as a separate task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you use a `function` not a an arrow function (`=>`) in regular functions, unless otherwise specified, `this` is of type `any`. So you are defining a function that returns `any` and assigning it to a function that is expected to return `Course`. But since `any` can be assigned to anything, the compiler allows this (`var something: any; var c: Course = something;` is valid for example)

I don't think the code actually has the behavior you intended. If you wanted to return `this` as in the current object, you should have used an arrow function, and that would have resulted in an error (`this.enroller = ()=> this;`). In your code since no one specifies who `this` is for your anonymous function it will probably be the window object.

To protect yourself against this type of error you could enable `noImplicitThis` compiler flag, this will not type `this` as any and the problem would be avoided.

Comment: Thanks Titian. Everything you say makes sense. I wrote up a really simple example to demonstrate the issue. In my actual code, the classes are very differentiated in their members. I understand all of your reasoning, but this example: let cFn2 : ()=> Course = ()=> new Instructor(); is essentially the one I am complaining about. The editor does not highlight this as an error although it obviously is one. I will edit my question to reflect that the classes have different properties.

Comment: @mhermher is it just an editor problem ? Do you get compilation errors ?

Comment: @mhermher Also what version of TS do you use ? I am on 2.6 and with your latest example, the error is highlighted in the editor.

Comment: Whoa ok. Nevermind. The edited version does produce an error. There is something actually different in some way about my actual code version that is not setting off the error. Thanks for your help, I need to identify a better minimal example.

Comment: Hi Titian, sorry to waste your time on this, but see the last edit. The behavior I am seeing is actually in the constructor, so that may be some special case.

Comment: @mhermher totally different problem, edited the answer, saved my previous answer since I may use it in other places :)

Comment: @mhermher Added suggestion to avoid this issue in the future

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I didn't realize what I had done! Thanks. Changing it to an arrow function highlights the error. Now I feel stupid, but thanks.